# How can I randomly load a single image from my Image directory using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, image, file, random, load

I'm very new to Jquery/Javascript and I'd like to load a single image onto my homepage from my image directory so that upon refreshing a new random image appears. Is there a way for Jquery to simply access my images folder and load any image at random? I am currently using a JS code that requires I type each image name that I would like loaded. This is exhaustive and while I may not know much about Jquery, I think this can be done in a cleaner fashion. my apologies in advance if i'm being naive.

Comment: you should just be able to link to them directly.

Comment: what do you mean? I'd like a new image upon the page loading

Comment: I mean images are resources that can be directly accessed relative to the current script execution.

Answer (score 3):

When you link to the them in your HTML markup you can use the same link in a js function to link to them like so.

Not sure how your directory structure is set up but as an example.

- dir

  - images

    - image1.jpg
  - scripts

    - script.js
  - style
  - index.html

in your js file you can just link to `images/image1.jpg`

in the `<header>` tag add:

```
<script type="text/js" src="js/script.js" />
```

Then in your script.js file do one of these:

```
//Raw Javascript

  function changeMe()
  {
    document.getElementById("changeMe").src = "images/" + getRandomImage();
  }

  <img id="changeMe" onLoad="changeMe()" src="images/default.jpg" />


 //JQuery
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#changeMe").src("images/" + getRandomImage());
  });
```

```
  <img id="changeMe" src="images/default.jpg" />
```

Then all you need to do is write the function that will return a random image from that directory. There are tons of ways to do this but for simplicity.

```
function getRandomImage() {
  var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];

  return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pd671zrm/1/)

Comment: This is a good answer. For the getRandomImage() function, it would be better to multiply by the array length, in case it contains less or more keys: `return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];`

Comment: That works, but I just threw it together quick to give an example. Edited per your suggestion

Comment: thanks a ton for this! but, I'm wondering... this looks like i'd have to define all the images in my image directory. (function getRandomImage() {
  var images = ["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg"];), is there a way to simply link it to my directory without having to define the images I want loaded? as in, letting jquery or JS choose whatever is in my image folder?

Comment: I just used it as an example, you will need to expand upon this idea to suit your own needs.