# How would I randomize a Landing page's background image using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, background-image

I want to do a simple project as something to add to my portfolio. I want to take a simple bootstrap landing page and have it randomly reload the background image and a quote across the screen when a button is clicked. I'm working with JS/Jquery Any tips or suggestions?

Finally got it to work this is for randomly choosing both a stored image and a quote on a button click:

```
    var bgimage = [/* images go here */];
    var quotes = [/* quotes go here */];
    $("#changer").click(function() {

    $(document.body).css({'background-image': 'url(CSS/backgrounds/' + 
        bgImage[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgImage.length)] + ')'
    });
    $('#quote').text(quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]
    );
```

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, using Ajax or without Ajax. According to the culture of this site, you might want to first show the community the actual code that you've tried :)

Comment: the first tip and suggestion would be asking you to actually try it.. if you face any problem, bring it to stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952820/how-can-i-randomly-load-a-single-image-from-my-image-directory-using-jquery

Comment: How is this relevant to [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3]?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for the layout, thought it was relevant in case there were any restrictions in what I could do using it

Comment: Syntax error `$(#changer)` should be `$("#changer")`. I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by simple PHP 
here is the code 
first this PHP

```html
<?php
    $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg','bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames
    $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
    $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename  was chosen
    ?>
```

then add this in your website ... as inline CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

how it will work 
you will list the photos you have 
the for each page load it will select one on random and show it .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in JS

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'];
 $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
</script>
```

its up to you to use the JS or PHP 
but the PHP is better because image will start load when visitor go to your site in JS it will load after full html and JS load .

Comment: Thanks for the input! It took me an hour, but I finally got it to change the background image upon clicking the button

Comment: ok good so please make the answer so other people will benefit from it and the Question will mark as resolved

Comment: Why in the css property do you use the brackets and semi-colon for the background image instead of something like .css(property,value)? I'm still learning I just want to better understand what's going on